# OkNegotiatedContentResult<T> is taking forever to return the value

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a query that is returning over 10,000 rows of data which is, I realize, a lot of data, but it is taking over two minutes for the UI to present this information. After some debugging, it turns out the pinch point is coming *after* the API Controller receives the data from the business service, not during the querying process.

Controller snippet:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetData()
{
  try
  {
     var myList = _myService.GetData(); //this takes about 9 seconds

     if (myList.Any())
     {
        return Ok(myList); //this takes two minutes or more
     }
```

Within the service, the data is being mapped to a user-defined model which consists of 80+ fields (only 10 of which are actually being assigned during method execution):

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Nickname { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Stepping through the code reveals that the line *return Ok(myList);* creates a record by record loop-through of *MyModel* where each of those 80+ fields is put through the get/set process.

So 10,000 rows of data, each one being looped to check 80+ fields (only 10 of which have values), and now we have a process that takes two minutes, far too long for the user to sit through.

I've not worked with *return Ok()* before, so is there a faster way to do this? What exactly is *return Ok()* doing with my data?

**UPDATED with GetData() Code**

```
public IList<MyModel> GetData()
{
  IList<Person> getPersonList = _dataService.getPersonList();

  IList<MyModel> returnList = new List<MyModel>();

   foreach (var p in getPersonList)
   {
      MyModel m = new MyModel();

      m.Id = p.PersonId;
      m.Name = p.PersonName;
      m.Address = p.PersonAddress;
      etc.
      returnList.Add(m);
    }

  return returnList;
}
```

Comment: Post the GetData() code, I assume you forgot a ToList somewhere.

Comment: Added, per your request.

Comment: `Ok(T item)` will serialize the content to (xml,json,something) and return that to the caller. Yeah, 10.000 records at 80 fields a record is going to create a fairly large chunk of serialized text. If you want to speed it up then only return what is necessary or batch/page the result with some input parameters. There is **usually** no need to return 10,000 records from a call.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case.

Comment: Not sure who the caller is but if you can change the API take a look at the Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.OData`. It allows you to very easily expose query points to your client as well as limit the result set (lets say to 100 so there is no abuse accidental or on purpose). You then specify a request using a query string, everything from filtering to paging to sorting is supported. So if the reason you have the above is to save some server side coding this might be a good answer for you.